# Django Image Upload in Database Absolute Path Rather Than Relative

Tags: python, json, django, image, django-rest-framework

My model:

```
class MedicineType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', max_length=255, null=True)
```

in **settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Now, when I do upload image from the browser, the url of the image is being stored in the database as an absolute path. For example, an image named 'example.png' is going to have

```
http://localhost:8000/media/images/example.png
```

But I want that only the relative path would be stored in the database. Not with the localhost and port. How Do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you do what?

What makes you think Django stores `http://localhost:8000/media/images/example.png` in your database? If that is what django does, then by changing your port at `python manage runserver 8010` means all your uploaded stuff break?

No, that's not what Django does. See [this from the documentation](http://devdocs.io/django~1.11/topics/files):

```
>>> car = Car.objects.get(name="57 Chevy")
>>> car.photo
<ImageFieldFile: chevy.jpg>
>>> car.photo.name
'cars/chevy.jpg'
>>> car.photo.path
'/media/cars/chevy.jpg'
>>> car.photo.url
'http://media.example.com/cars/chevy.jpg'
```

The above should explain enough what is happening. Check the link above for more details.

The `car.photo.name` **IS** what Django stored in the Database. The `car.photo.url` or `care.photo.path` then is what *you think* was stored in the Database.

Comment: I have used get request to get the data in json format. I saw that the image url is being saved in that way.